# How can I contain a label on a Highcharts area chart to the series' area

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For some reason no matter what we try the labels on our area chart series seem to have a mind of their own. Even though a short label looks like it could fit inside the area of the data, it puts it right on the end line, bleeding out of the area.

We suspect it might be due to having min and max dates that are beyond the series min and max, but these buffer zones are a requirement.

Is there an option to make labels be contained to their own series and not bleed off into whitespace?

Below is the example chart configuration and here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sLqu34cn/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: "area",
    height: 200
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      stacking: "percent",
      pointPlacement: "on"
    },
    series: {
      lineWidth: 0,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      label: {
        style: {
          color: "white",
          textOutline: "1px black"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Two",
      data: [[1532217600000, 1], [1532822400000, 0]],
      color: "#41B6E6"
    },
    {
      name: "Three",
      data: [[1532217600000, 0], [1532822400000, 2]],
      color: "#0072CE"
    }
  ],
  xAxis: {
    tickWidth: 1,
    title: {
      enabled: false
    },
    labels: {
      format: "{value: %b %e}"
    },
    max: 1533243166375,
    min: 1530478366375,
    type: "datetime"
  },
  yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 20,
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    labels: {
      format: "{value}%"
    },
    max: 100,
    min: 0
  },
  tooltip: {}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the perfect solution, but you can create some customization to position the series labels. This is an example how to manually calculate the center of area in triangle shape:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'drawSeriesLabels', function(proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    var chart = this,
        plotTop = chart.plotTop,
        plotLeft = chart.plotLeft,
        series = chart.series,
        height = chart.yAxis[0].height,
        x1,
        x2,
        y1,
        y2;

    x1 = ((series[0].graphPath[1] + plotLeft) * 2 + series[0].graphPath[4] + plotLeft) / 3;

    y1 = (height + plotTop + series[0].graphPath[2] + plotTop + series[0].graphPath[5] + plotTop) / 3;

    x2 = (series[1].graphPath[1] + plotLeft + (series[1].graphPath[4] + plotLeft) * 2) / 3;

    y2 = ((series[1].graphPath[2] + plotTop) * 2 + series[1].graphPath[5] + plotTop) / 3;

    series[0].labelBySeries.attr({
        x: x1,
        y: y1,
        align: 'center'
    });

    series[1].labelBySeries.attr({
        x: x2,
        y: y2,
        align: 'center'
    });
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/34z8od5f/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts